# Geometric mean of two numbers

Tags: mean

I need to find the geometric mean of 0 and 600. Would it  just be the square root of 600? I know that the formula is 
$$
\bar x_{\mathrm{GM}} = \left(x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n\right)^{1/n}, 
$$
but in this case one of my values is 0, so I'm not sure.

Comment: nop, it's 0. Geometric means is 0 whenever any single one of the x_i is not strictly positive....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should trust the formula: it is zero. (Whether it is useful to talk about the geometric mean of a list including zero is a different question.)